# Gitlab CI/CD with Terraform and 3rd party plugin

Tags: gitlab, terraform, gitlab-ci

I'm provisioning resources on AWS as well as on a 3rd party system via a custom provider. On my local environment, it works fine (as I have downloaded and compiled the 3rd party provider).

As a next step, I’m trying to run a Gitlab pipeline with Terraform.The AWS part works because it's a Terrafrom registered provider, however the 3rd party part fails (because it's not a registered Terraform provider).

When I try to run a Gitlab pipeline, it complains with an error and advises the following

> In the latter case, the plugin must be installed manually by locating
>   and downloading a suitable distribution package and placing the
>   plugin’s executable file in the following directory:
>   terraform.d/plugins/linux_amd64

The .gitlab-ci.yml file I have is the following:

```
image:
  name: hashicorp/terraform:light
  entrypoint:
    - '/usr/bin/env'
    - 'PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin'

before_script:
  - rm -rf .terraform
  - terraform --version
  - export AWS_ACCESS_KEY
  - export AWS_SECRET_KEY
  - terraform init

stages:
  - validate
  - plan
  - apply

validate:
  stage: validate
  script:
    - terraform validate

plan:
  stage: plan
  script:
    - terraform plan -out "planfile"
  dependencies:
    - validate
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - planfile

apply:
  stage: apply
  script:
    - terraform apply -input=false "planfile"
  dependencies:
    - plan
  when: manual
```

[image]

I see an image is used called 'hashicorp/terraform:light'. Should I create a docker image based on this image with the 3rd party provider already in?

### EDIT1

It's clear a custom image is required. I used the idea from rflume below and used the following Dockerfile to build the image.

```
# Multi-Stage builds require Docker Engine 17.05 or higher

# Build ACI provider
FROM ubuntu:bionic-20190515 as builder

ENV HOME /root
ENV GOPATH $HOME/go
ENV GOBIN $GOPATH/bin

RUN apt update &&\
    apt install -yqq software-properties-common \
    git \
    wget \
    unzip \
    gcc \
    perl \
    go-dep \
    make \
    build-essential &&\
    add-apt-repository ppa:longsleep/golang-backports &&\
    apt-get update &&\
    apt-get install -y golang-go &&\
    mkdir -p $GOPATH/src/github.com/terraform-providers &&\
    wget -O $HOME/terraform-provider-aci.zip https://github.com/ciscoecosystem/terraform-provider-aci/archive/master.zip &&\
    cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/terraform-providers/ &&\
    unzip $HOME/terraform-provider-aci.zip -d . &&\
    mv terraform-provider-aci-master \
    terraform-provider-aci-v1.0.0

WORKDIR $GOPATH/src/github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aci-v1.0.0

RUN dep ensure
RUN make build


# Build the actual image
FROM hashicorp/terraform:0.11.14


ENV GOBIN /root/go/bin
ENV PATH $GOBIN:$PATH

RUN mkdir -p /root/.terraform.d/plugins

COPY --from=builder /root/go/bin/terraform-provider-aci-v1.0.0 $GOBIN/terraform-provider-aci-v1.0.0

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to create an image with the custom provider already in.

```
FROM hashicorp/terraform:full

ENV GOPATH /go

RUN mkdir -p $GOPATH/src/github.com/ciscoecosystem
WORKDIR $GOPATH/src/github.com/ciscoecosystem
RUN git clone https://github.com/ciscoecosystem/terraform-provider-aci.git $GOPATH/src/github.com/ciscoecosystem/terraform-provider-aci
RUN git clone https://github.com/ciscoecosystem/aci-go-client.git $GOPATH/src/github.com/ciscoecosystem/aci-go-client
RUN apk add --no-cache build-base

WORKDIR $GOPATH/src/github.com/ciscoecosystem/terraform-provider-aci

RUN make build

WORKDIR $GOPATH

ENTRYPOINT ["terraform"]
```

Answer (score 0):

The `terraform:light` image does not contain 3rd party providers. You can try using `terraform:full` image but you might have no luck with that one either.

In this case you'd have to build your own image based on one of the above images (preferably `light`, the smaller the image the better...).

I've had the same problem and built an image based on `light` with the AWS provider and an 3rd party Ansible provisioner [Terraform-with-AWS-Provisioner-and-Ansible-Provider-for-Gitlab-CI](https://github.com/rflume/Terraform-with-AWS-Provisioner-and-Ansible-Provider-for-Gitlab-CI/blob/master/Dockerfile) which you can use as reference if you like.

**EDIT1 (regarding your edit):**

What I noticed is that you don't specify a provider version in your `COPY --from=builder ...` command. According to [Plugin Names and Versions](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/providers.html#plugin-names-and-versions), you need to specify a version for the provider with `_v[VERSION]` to your built provider package though.
Try that and let me know if it works then ;)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will need to build an image indeed. Why not simply do:   FROM hashicorp/terraform:light
RUN mkdir -p /root/.terraform.d/plugins
ADD terraform-provider-aci  /root/.terraform.d/plugins

Comment: I used multi-stage build to keep the image as small as possible (in the fial images the build dependencies are not included anymore etc.). Also I need some files to store the secrets in, such as an SSH key for Ansible. You can also do it as you suggested if that's sufficient for your use case.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand. The first stage is the compilation of your custom provider, the second stage creates the Terraform image that can be used in the Gitlab pipeline?

Comment: Exactly. `COPY --from=builder /root/go/bin/terraform-provider-aws $GOBIN/terraform-provider-aws_v$AWS_PROVIDER_VERSION` copies the compiled provider from the build stage into the final image. Among the other setup commands that are required for the final image. When you run `docker build ` against this Dockerfile, *only* the image of the second stage is preserved (and pushed to the registry).

Comment: Brilliant. Will try out. Thanks!!

Comment: Trying to understand exactly what you do after the COPY cmd in the second stage. Guess I do not understand why you need to wget and chmod things (as you have copied over the compiler provider already before)

Comment: In the build stage the `aws-provider` is downloaded an built, in the final image though I also need the `ansible-provisioner` which is a 3rd-party plugin. This one doesn't require a build from source but is instead downloaded directly "into the final image".

Comment: I added in the original post (EDIT1) my current Dockerfile. Care to have a look? When I use this image in my Gitlab CICD, I get exactly the same error. Maybe you see something wrong?

Comment: The provider as such does not come with a specific version. I'm cloning basically the master repo.

Comment: Then just try to add `_v1.0.0` to the provider package. I think it doesn't even matter as long as to don't refer to a specific provider version in Terraform itself.

Comment: Tried it out, but results in same error. I put in EDIT1 my last code. Running out of ideas ... :-)

Comment: You added `-v1.0.0`, not `_v1.0.0.` (underscore!)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Been testing this weekend. No, did not solve the issue. I have been trying another method which worked.